# BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap_Image) giving error while setting custom markers on Google Map v2

Tags: android, dictionary, android-maps-v2

```
LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.test2);
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v.buildDrawingCache();
final Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
BitmapDescriptor iconBitmap = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);


MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude[i], longitude[i])).title(name[i]).
                            alpha((float) 0.8).
                            title("3.5").
                            icon(iconBitmap);
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

It is throwing the following error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: Since `getDrawingCache()` can return `null`, my guess is that is your problem. Use a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, not `getDrawingCache()`, for rendering your `LinearLayout` into a `Bitmap`.

Comment: But @CommonsWare when setting this bitmap to a imageView like        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm); It is giving proper output

Comment: Switch to using a plain icon instead of using your generated `Bitmap`. If the problem goes away, the problem is with your generated `Bitmap`. If the problem persists, then the problem is with the parameters you are passing into the `MarkerOptions` builder methods.